# Access a dictionary key from another dictionary in plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, plist, info.plist

[image][image: plist of Dealers and Cars]

I want to have access to the dealer name from the `plist`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Cars" ofType:@"plist"];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableArray *dealers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *object in array) {
    Dealer *dealer = [[Dealer alloc] initWithDictionary:object];
    [dealers addObject:dealer];
}
self.dealers = dealers;
```

From this, i access just the first dictionary from `plist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `NSDictinonary` in you plist has `Item 0` key that store Dealer `NSDictinonary`. Change your string code

```
 Dealer *dealer = [[Dealer alloc] initWithDictionary:object];
```

to this

```
 Dealer *dealer = [[Dealer alloc] initWithDictionary:object[@"Dealer"]];
```

Comment: @Ionut Bronze  I saw your plist again and update answer, you have a NSDictionay by key @"Dealer"

Comment: And if I want to access the Cars Dictionary, how can I do this?

Comment: for access Cars you need call like this `object[@"Dealer"][@"Cars"]`

Comment: Check that all of your Dealer `NSDictionay ` has a Cars `NSArray`

Comment: I checked that, all my dealers have the same components

Comment: could you provide a crash log?

Comment: iOS_CarsApplication[3515:157640] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa24b750f70
2016-07-22 12:49:38.833 iOS_CarsApplication[3515:157640] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa24b750f70'

Comment: it happend because one of your object in plist is not a `NSDictinonary` or you try parse Cars as a `NSDictinonary ` but it as a `NSArray `

Answer (score -1):

i recommend you check the variables-array,object